# Why are localized functions faster in Lua?

Tags: performance, lua

> #### TEST 1: Localize
>
> **Code:**
>
> ```
> local min = math.min
> ```
>
> **Results:**
>
> *Non-local: 0.719 (158%)*
>   *Localized: 0.453 (100%)*
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> *Yes, we should localize all standard lua and Spring API functions.*

Source: https://springrts.com/wiki/Lua_Performance

What is the reason for that performance boost?

Comment: Accessing local variable is just reading a value from some stack location.  On the contrary, `math.min` means double looking into hash-part of table (searching `math` in globals table and searching `min` in table `math`) using  CPU-intensive calculations of hash-function values of strings `math` and `min`.

Comment: Try your timings also with just `local math = math` instead of `local min = math.min`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any performance value in creating local copies of Lua functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093728/is-there-any-performance-value-in-creating-local-copies-of-lua-functions)

Comment: This has nothing to do with functions, that is, the types of the values being accessed. It just relates to the complexity of the expression being evaluated to obtain the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> local min = math.min

Remember that `table.name` is just syntax sugar for `table["name"]` (they're exactly equivalent). And globals are just keys in the environment table, so `math.min` is `_ENV["math"]["min"]`. That's two hashtable lookups to get at the actual function value.

Copying the value into a `local` puts it in a VM register so there's no lookup.