# Why `local print = print` in Lua?

Tags: lua, local

While learning from third party's Lua code, I found at the top of the main script file

```
local insert = table.insert
local match = string.match
local gsub = string.gsub
```

I understand these chunks as shortcut definitions, but I also found

```
local assert = assert
local ipairs = ipairs
local print = print
```

What is the purpose of these last instructions ?

Comment: Some people overdo this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing locals is faster. So in some cases it might make sense to make frequently used things local to save a few percent of processing time. But in most cases there you can save yourself the trouble. Especially if a global isn't used thousands of times.

Give this a read:

[Why are local variables accessed faster than global variables in lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132288/why-are-local-variables-accessed-faster-than-global-variables-in-lua)

http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisingUsingLocalVariables

Comment: Here's another resource: [Lua Performance Tips](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf). It specifically mentions this pattern on page 17, but it talks specifically about functions being called in a loop, not just any function used in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It increase a little bit performance in some workload

reason why:
[Why are localized functions faster in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945039/why-are-localized-functions-faster-in-lua)