# Local declaration of (built-in) Lua functions to reduce overhead

Tags: performance, lua

It is often said that one should re-declare (certain) Lua functions locally, as this reduces the overhead.
But what is the exact rule / principle behind this? How do I know for which functions this should be done and for which it is superfluous? Or should it be done for EVERY function, even your own?

Unfortunately I can't figure it out from the Lua manual.

Comment: See [Lua Performance Tips](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any performance value in creating local copies of Lua functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093728/is-there-any-performance-value-in-creating-local-copies-of-lua-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The principle is that every time you write `table.insert` for example, the Lua interpreter looks up the `"insert"` entry in the table called `table`. Actually, it means `_ENV.table.insert` - `_ENV` is where the "global variables" are in Lua 5.2+. Lua 5.1 has something similar but it's not called `_ENV`. The interpreter looks up the string `"table"` in `_ENV` and then looks up the string `"insert"` in that table. Two table lookups every time you call `table.insert`, before the function actually gets called.

But if you put it in a local variable then the interpreter gets the function directly from the local variable, which is faster. It still has to look it up, to fill in the local variable.

It is superfluous if you only call the function once within the scope of the local variable, but that is pretty rare. There is no reason to do it for functions which are already declared as `local`. It also makes the code harder to read, so typically you won't do it except when it actually matters (in code that runs a lot of times).

Answer (score 1):

My favorit tool for speed up things in Lua is to place all the useable stuff for a table in a metatable called: __index
A common example for this is the datatype: string
It has all string functions in his __index metatable as methods.
Therefore you can do things like that directly on a string...

```
print(('istaqsinaayok'):upper():reverse())
-- Output: KOYAANISQATSI
```

The Logic above...
The lookup for a method in a string fails directly and therefore the __index metamethod will be looked up for that method.

I like to implement same behaviour for the datatype number...

```
-- do debug.setmetatable() only once for all further defined/used numbers
math.pi = debug.setmetatable(math.pi, {__index = math})
-- From now numbers are objects ;-)
-- Lets output Pi but not using Pi this time
print((180):rad()) -- Pi calcing with method rad()
-- Output: 3.1415926535898
```

The Logic: If not exists then lookup __index
Is only one step behind: local
...imho.

Another Example, that works with this method...

```
-- koysenv.lua
_G = setmetatable(_G,
{ -- Metamethods
 __index = {}, -- Table constructor
 __name = 'Global Environment'
})

-- Reference whats in _G into __index
for key, value in pairs(_G) do
 getmetatable(_G)['__index'][key] = value
end

-- Remove all whats in __index now from _G
for key, value in pairs(getmetatable(_G)['__index']) do
 _G[key] = nil
end

return _G
```

When started as a last require it move all in _G into fresh created metatable method __index.
After that _G looks totally empty ;-P
...but the environment is working like nothing happen.

Comment: Using `__index` doesn't really speed things up (except for strings) - quite the opposite. In the end you still have to do the hash lookup.

Comment: You don't need `math.pi = ` in your `debug.setmetatable` example.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @user253751 already said:

## Code Quality

Lua is a very flexible language. Other languages require you to import the parts of the standard library you use; Lua doesn't. Lua usually provides one global environment not to be polluted. If you play with the environment `_ENV` (`setfenv`/`getfenv` on Lua 5.1 / LuaJIT), you'll want to be able to still access Lua libraries. For that purpose you may to localize them before changing the environment; you can then use your "clean" environment for your module / API table / class / whatever. Another option here is to use metatables; metatable chains may quickly get hairy though and are likely to harm performance, as a failed table lookup is required each time to trigger indexing metamethods. `local`izing otherwise global variables can thus be seen as a way of importing them; to give a minimal & rough example:

```lua
local print = print -- localize ("import") everything we need first
_ENV = {} -- set environment to clean table for module
function hello() -- this writes to _ENV instead of _G
    print("Hello World!")
end
hello() -- inside the environment, all variables set here are accessible
return _ENV -- "export" the API table
```

## Performance

Very minor nitpick: Local variables aren't strictly *always* faster. In very extreme cases (i.e. *lots of upvalues*), indexing a table (which doesn't need an upvalue if it's the environment, the string metatable or the like) may actually be faster.

I imagine that localizing variables is required for many optimizations of optimizing compilers such as LuaJIT to be applicable though; otherwise Lua makes very little code. A global like `print` might as well be overwritten somewhere in a deep code path - thus the indexing operation has to be repeated every time; for a local on the other hand, the interpreter will has way more guarantees regarding its scope. It is thus able to detect constants that are only written to once, on initialization for instance; for globals very little code analysis is possible.