# Get global environment in lua package

Tags: lua, package, global

At the begining of some lua package files, sometimes there will be the line `local base = _G` or `local base = ...`.

1. What's the benefits for doing this?
2. What's the differences between these two lines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9198758/3166303

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why make global Lua functions local?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198677/why-make-global-lua-functions-local)

Comment: @hjpotter92 But what about the second question?

Comment: `local base = ...` means that a value for variable `base` (globals table?) is expected to be in first argument to this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can refer: [Why make global Lua functions local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198677/why-make-global-lua-functions-local)

For your second one,

> What's the differences between these two lines?

When you do `local base = _G`, you are assigning `base` to be a synonym for the global environment table. On the other hand, in the statement `local base = ...`; the `...` refer to [`vararg` feature](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.2.html) of lua.

It can be shown in better detail with the following example:

```
local a = {...}
for k, v in pairs(a) do print(k, v) end
```

and then, executing it as follows:

```
─$ lua temp.lua some thing is passed "here within quotes"
1       some
2       thing
3       is
4       passed
5       here within quotes
```

As you see, `...` is just a list of arguments passed to the program. Now, when you have

```
local base = ...
```

lua assigns the first argument to the variable `base`. All other parameters will be ignored in the above statement.

Comment: So with the second statement one need to pass `_G` as the argument when loading the package file. Is it right?